# Hadoop eclipse mapreduce is not working?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I just have copied `hadoop-eclipse-plugin-1.0.3.jar` to the eclipse/plugins directory in order to get things going. But unfortunately it did not work for me. When I tried to connect eclipse to my *Hadoop Version 1.1.1* cluster it threw this error :

```
An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status updater". org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException
```

Is there any option to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the port numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Just follow these steps** :

1- Go to your `HADOOP_HOME/contrib` folder. Copy the `hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*.jar` somewhere and extract it. This will give a folder named `hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*`

2- Now, add following 5 jars from your HADOOP_HOME/lib folder to the hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*/lib folder, you have got just now after extracting the plugin :

```
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar
```

3- Now, modify the `hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file and change the Bundle-ClassPath to :
Bundle-ClassPath: classes /,

```
lib / hadoop-core.jar, 
lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar,
lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar, 
lib/jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar , 
lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar, 
lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar, 
lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar
```

4- Now, re 'jar' the package and place this new jar inside eclipse/plugin directory and restart the eclipse.

and also check [this](https://mtariq.jux.com/goinggeek/797614) link.