# Hadoop with eclipse is not connecting

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to connect hadoop in eclipse.Successfully installed plugin for 1.04. I am using java 1.7 for this.

My configuration data are 
                         username:hduser,locationname:test,map/reduce host port are localhost:9101 and M/R masterhost localhost:9100.

My temp directory is /app/hduser/temp.
As per this location I set advanced parameters.But I was not able to set fs.s3.buffer.dir as there was no such directory created like /app/hadoop/tmp//s3. unable to set map reduce master directory.I only found local directory. I didnot find mapred.jobtracker.persist.job.dir. And also map red temp dir.

When I ran hadoop in pseudo distributed mode I didnot found any datanode running also with JPS.

I am  not sure what is the problem here.In eclipse I got the error while setting the dfs server.I got the message like...

An internal error occurred during: "Connecting to DFS test".
org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration

Thanks all

Comment: Can you paste the error in logs here? and tell me please that are you able to start hadoop successfully?

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-04-04 00:24:13.917
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status updater".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException

Comment: then please paste it as answer so it would be helpuful for the future visitors

Comment: Problem was with the eclipse plugin version.I built the hadoop eclipse plugin from source and used it.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Later found this:
[Hadoop eclipse mapreduce is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195734/hadoop-eclipse-mapreduce-is-not-working)

The main blog post is [this](http://cloudfront.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-run-mapreduce-programs-using.html#.UY7PR6DQWKg). HTH someone who is looking for a solution.