# Eclipse plugin error for Hadoop on Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I installed Hadoop version 1.0.3 and its related eclipse plugin successfully. All the Hadoop functionalities and examples are working pretty well, but when I want to use its plugin on eclipse, it could not connect to hdfs and I get the error:

**An internal error occurred during: "Connecting to DFS localhost".
org/apache/commons/configurati­on/Configuration.**

could anybody help me how to solve this problem!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because the plugin is missing some necessary jars. In order to solve the problem you need to rebuild the plugin after including the necessary jars. I have seen this kind of questions a lot on SO, and they all point out to the same thing. Please see these links :

[Eclipse Hadoop plugin issue(Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50070 )Can any body give me the solution for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591777/eclipse-hadoop-plugin-issuecall-to-localhost-127-0-0-150070-can-any-body-give/13604899#13604899)

[Hadoop eclipse mapreduce is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195734/hadoop-eclipse-mapreduce-is-not-working)

[Installing Hadoop's Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782042/installing-hadoops-eclipse-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I did follow the following blog instructions to make Hadoop eclipse plugin 1.0.4 :
http://iredlof.com/part-4-compile-hadoop-v1-0-4-eclipse-plugin-on-ubuntu-12-10/

but it seems it has some missing parts like:

in **MANIFEST.MF** you should add:

```
/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
```

and in **build-contrib.xml** you should also add:

```
<property name="commons-cli.version" value="1.2"/>
```

I hope these are useful!

Answer (score 0):

you must run hadoop with command line first!!

```
./[hadoop-path]/bin/start-all.sh
```